# A loop for collecting events from sql so as not to lose any events

Tags: python, pandas, loops, clickhouse

I have a database to which logs are sent, new records are constantly appearing in the table. I need to make a loop to read 10,000 records at a time and not lose any.

I thought that I could somehow use last_value (sql) in the time column: My_time. But I can't figure out how to make the loop logic to somehow remember the last_value and start loading events from the event with this time again. I need to upload 10,000 pieces each.

```
with sshtunnel.SSHTunnelForwarder(
     ('10.x.x.x', 22),
     ssh_username=ssh_username,
     ssh_password=ssh_password,
     remote_bind_address=('localhost', 9000)) as server:
          local_port = server.local_bind_port
          conn = connect(f'clickhouse://{click_username}:{click_password}@localhost: local_port}/My_table')
          last_point = pd.read_sql("""SELECT last_value(My_time) as last_point FROM My_table.event LIMIT 10000""", conn)
          table = pd.read_sql("""SELECT * FROM My_table.event WHERE My_time > (SELECT last_value(My_time) as last_point FROM My_table.event LIMIT 10000) """, conn)
          print(table)
```

Comment: If you have an id column then store that outside of the query itself and supply it back as a parameter. I wouldn't rely on `last_value()`

Comment: I don't have a column: id ((